# Force an image to display as block (not inline)

Tags: blocks, 9

I have a field of type image that I would like to display in a column alone, with all following content displaying beneath, even if the image width is narrower than the width of the display.

Even when using the layout builder, the following content always flows inline with the image.  The image is in a block in a single column section.  The following content is in a two-column section.  Instead of a single column showing the image followed by two columns with other content, the resulting display appears as three columns: Image of 1st section, 1st column of 2nd section, then 2nd column of 2nd section all in a single row.

Drupal version: 9.1.4

Any assistance in solving this?

Comment: Not sure why the downvote... I googled extensively without finding a solution. Display suite does work as expected, so why does layout builder work differently?

Comment: I am pretty sure I am missing something here but sorry to ask: why you don't use a CSS solution for this?

Comment: I was under the impression that the layout builder in Drupal core worked that way, where a section was a block element.  It doesn't make sense for a section to contain a specific number of columns if that section is displayed alongside the previous section as additional columns.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be a CSS issue, not a Drupal issue. Leverage "display:block" and "min-width:100%" on whichever wrapper div you want to stay on top. But you'll need some CSS massaging and experimenting to get it working as you need.